# Добавление ipv6 в ipset

Tags: linux, ip, iptables, firewall, ipset

Можно ли добавить подсеть IPv6 в CIDR формате в ipset и как это делается? Можно ли добавлять одновременно в один список подсетей ipset IPv4 и IPv6. Приведите пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя. Необходимо создать два списка. Один для IPv4, другой для IPv6.При желании можно создать лист из двух этих списков.

```
ipset create badips iphash family net
ipset create badips6 iphash family net6
```